# Don't close PopupMenu on MenuItem-Click

Tags: android, android-actionbar, popupmenu

I need to show a few items in a popup menu. They are dynamically downloaded and added to PopupMenu which is shown on button's click.

```
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, view);
        Menu menu = popupMenu.getMenu();

        for (Category c : categories) {
            menu.add(c.getName()).setCheckable(true);
        }

        popupMenu.show();
```

I enabled the possibility to check or uncheck the items, but I want that the user can check or uncheck more then just one item. At the moment this is not possible, because the PopupMenu is closed as the user clicks on an item.

Has anybody done this before or has an idea to achieve my demand?

Comment: do you solved your problem?

Answer (score -3):

When you override `public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)` to handle the click event, return `false` instead of `true`. This will tell the system that the menu click is not finished being handled and it will not close it.

Comment: I tried both possibilities but neither `true` nor `false` brought the solution.

Comment: Is there documentation that the return value controls this behaviour? It makes sense, but I can't find it in the official docs. Like JU5T1c3, neither a `true` or `false` value seems to stop the closing of the popup for me.